# jquery validation regex for digits with hyphens

Tags: jquery, regex

Can someone provide a regex that only allows digits and optionally hyphens

I have got as far as phone_number.match(/[0-9-]/); but with no luck

Comment: Do you want to validate U.S phone numbers ?

Comment: yes but only want to validate if number as the user can input without hyphens so 5454542542542 or 542542-54254254-542 would pass?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following matches numbers interspersed with dashes, but not double dashes:

```
/^\d+(-\d+)*$/
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is used in the jquery validate plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/phoneUS

```
^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$
```

I came here searching for something similar and found what I needed at http://regexlib.com/ they have a great collection of expressions as well as a helpful cheat sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out...

```
/^[0-9]+(\-[0-9]+)*$/
```

Not phone numbers, but what you wanted from the comments

Comment: thanks but that allows letters after the numbers, such as 54hghgd is pass

Comment: no it doesn't ? if you want to match the whole string use `/^[0-9]+(\-[0-9])*$/`

Comment: using /^[0-9]+(\-[0-9])*$/ then 878-554 fails

Comment: it shouldn't, what exact code are you using and what exact string are you testing it on

Comment: In this case, there is no need to reinvent the wheel, imho. Use plugins

Comment: using jquery validation plugin and is a phone number which will be all digits (any length) and could have hyphens

Comment: *sigh*, i give up, the regex given works, I tested it here http://www.regextester.com/ if you're not going to post your code there's nothing more I can do

Comment: @Chimoo: it doesn't, the * is in the wrong place. It now matches numbers like 23523-3-5-6-7-8. The * should be before the close parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin: [Masked Input jQuery plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo). It allows to make own masks and simplifies input for user.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\w*-?\w*-?\w*$/
```

- **\w*** Alphanumeric character repeated 0 or many times.
- **-?** Optional hyphen.

Comment: need to adapt this to /^\d[-]?/ as length is variable but will still allow letters in the middle such as 6hjh36-6-53653

Answer (score 0):

```
Check this out...
```

> var phoneno = /^+?[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)*$/;
>
> Ans +954-555-1234

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for a input with hyphens

```js
$('input[type="tel"]').keyup(function() {
  this.value = this.value
    .match(/\d*/g).join('')
    .match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/).slice(1).join('-')
    .replace(/-*$/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="tel"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently developed a regex pattern for my assignment which exactly matches  999-999-9999.

> /^\d{3}-{1}\d{3}-{1}\d{4}$/

```
^ asserts position at start of a line
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
{3} matches the previous token exactly 3 times
- matches the character - with index 4510 (2D16 or 558) literally (case sensitive)
{1} matches the previous token exactly one time (meaningless quantifier)
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
{3} matches the previous token exactly 3 times
- matches the character - with index 4510 (2D16 or 558) literally (case sensitive)
{1} matches the previous token exactly one time (meaningless quantifier)
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
{4} matches the previous token exactly 4 times
$ asserts position at the end of a line
```